# Personal Teams App don't show on iOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, microsoft-teams

We created a **Teams Personal app** using the Teams Development Center. The app is displayed in the Teams client on all desktop devices (Windows, macOS) without any problems (desktop client and also in the web version). **On all Android and iOS devices, the app cannot be installed because it does not appear in the app selection**. Even an automatic installation using a setup Teams policy does not install the app in the mobile Teams clients. We have successfully tested if the app works in another tenant - result: on another tenant everything works fine. All Teams app policies have been thoroughly checked.
Is there a global policy in the tenant that prevents the Personal App from displaying?

- Reinstall mobile Teams App on iOS and Android --> no fix
- Check the Personal App in another tenant --> it works (but is not the solution)
- Check all the Teams-Policies in combination with apps --> all good

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1366804/teams-personal-app-is-not-showing-in-mobile-app-io. Please follow the Microsoft QnA thread for further updates. Thank you.